# Taking Julia code as input for Riemann sum function

Tags: julia, numerical-integration

I want to write a function that will calculate a Riemann sum given the integrand, limits of integration, and the number of subintervals to use. I'm trying to convert a string argument that specifies the function in Julia notation into an expression that can be evaluated within the function definition, however it keeps saying that the variable of the function is undefined.

```
function riemann_sum(f::String, a, b, n::Int64)
    if n < 1
        return error("n must be a positive integer")
    elseif a ≥ b
        return error("a must be less than b")
    end
    partition = []
    for i ∈ 0:n
        push!(partition, a + i * b / n)
    end
    tags = []
    for i ∈ 1:n
        push!(tags, (partition[i] + partition[i + 1]) / 2)
    end
    sum = 0
    for i ∈ 1:n
        x = tags[i]
        f = Meta.parse(f)
        tag_value = eval(f)
        rectangle =  tag_value * (partition[i + 1] - partition[i])
        sum += rectangle
    end
    return sum
end

println(riemann_sum("x ^ 2", 0, 2, 100))
```

Answer (score 3):

Definitely avoid parsing strings into functions. It is not good coding practice, and it is extremely inefficient. Your code has other issues, like an unnecessary vector, which is also untyped (`tags = []`).

You can do this much more simply, like this:

```
function riemann(f, a, b, n)
    x = range(a, b, n)
    return sum(f, x) * step(x)
end
```

Here we use a `range` object to construct the samples, and then a non-allocating sum. `step(x)` is the distance between samples.

Call it like this

```
riemann(x->x^2, 0, 2, 100)
```

**Edit:** To get it closer to the correct integral, sampling in the middle of each bin, this is a bit better:

```
function riemann(f, a, b, n)
    offset = (b - a) / 2n
    x = range(a + offset, b - offset, n)
    return sum(f, x) * step(x)
end
```

BTW, the reason your solution does not work, is that `eval` evaluates in global scope, not in your function scope. So if you have a variable `x` defined in global scope it will use that:

```
julia> foo(x, str) = eval(Meta.parse(str))

julia> foo(3, "x^2")
ERROR: UndefVarError: `x` not defined

julia> x = 5;

julia> foo(3, "x^2")
25
```

At any rate, using `eval` is bad practice, and should be avoided. Use anonymous functions/lambdas instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this. Just pass a function.

```
function riemann_sum(f, a, b, n::Int64)
    if n < 1
        return error("n must be a positive integer")
    elseif a ≥ b
        return error("a must be less than b")
    end
    partition = []
    for i ∈ 0:n
        push!(partition, a + i * b / n)
    end
    tags = []
    for i ∈ 1:n
        push!(tags, (partition[i] + partition[i + 1]) / 2)
    end
    sum = 0
    for i ∈ 1:n
        x = tags[i]
        tag_value = f(x)
        rectangle =  tag_value * (partition[i + 1] - partition[i])
        sum += rectangle
    end
    return sum
end

println(riemann_sum(x->x ^ 2, 0, 2, 100))
```